# Access token is missing, invalid or expired. In Axios POST Api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, http-post, crud

In order to upload the image to the server I have to use Axios, but first I have to get the apiKey and the access_token, I managed that and saved it in localStorage. When I try to upload an image to the server, I get a "403" error message, see the title. I don't know what could be causing it. Could someone please give me some advice as to what it could be? Thanks a lot

```
//Getting apiKey and save to loacalStorage as api
axios.post('https://URL/tenants', {
        "name": "user-name",
        "password": "user-password"
    })
        .then(res => {
            axios.defaults.headers['x-api-key'] = res.data.apiKey;

            localStorage.setItem("api", JSON.stringify(res.data.apiKey))
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```

```
//Getting access_token and save to localStorage
let apiString = localStorage.getItem("api").replaceAll('"', '');

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://URL/login',
        data: {
            "username": "user-name",
            "password": "user-password"
        },
        headers: {
            "X-API-KEY": apiString
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        axios.defaults.headers.post['X-API-KEY'] = localStorage.getItem("api")
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", JSON.stringify(response.data.access_token))

    }).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

When I try to get data from the api, I get an empty object as a response, which is correct and doesn't throw any error.

```
//get array or object from api

const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'URL/articles',
            data: {
    
            },
            headers: {
                "X-API-KEY": apiString,
                "Authorization": accessToken
            }
        }).then((response) => {
    
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => { console.log(error) }); */
```

But if I try to send data to the api, I get an error message 403 - Access token is missing, invalid or expired.

//uploading data to the server

```
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'URL/images',
        headers: {
            "X-API-KEY": apiString,
            "Authorization": accessToken
        },
        data: image
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);

    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
```

I don't understand why it doesn't accept access_token in this case... The documentation says that this API uses the CRUD method, I don't know if that has an effect. Thanks a lot

Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried what you wrote. Access_token is different in point 1 and 2 mentioned. According to the console, it looks like the old access_token is loaded first, then a 403 response is returned, and only then does the new access_token arrive, which is stored in localStorage. And it all gets called twice in a row. Below is a console listing.

```
loaded from localStorage: f284d0ab-2d8a-4a5e-b537-160d0819e7a6
VM344 installHook.js:1861 loaded from localStorage: f284d0ab-2d8a-4a5e-b537-160d0819e7a6
xhr.js:247          POST https://fullstack.exercise.applifting.cz/articles 403
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:142
wrap @ bind.js:5
App @ App.js:117
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20145
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
App.js:122 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: adapter: (2) ['xhr', 'http']data: "{\"title\":\"Titulek článku\",\"article\":\"text článku\"}"env: {FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}headers: AxiosHeaders {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Content-Type: 'application/json', X-API-KEY: 'b1d9a4f0-bfab-46bf-928c-71272e66000d', Authorization: 'f284d0ab-2d8a-4a5e-b537-160d0819e7a6'}maxBodyLength: -1maxContentLength: -1method: "post"timeout: 0transformRequest: [ƒ]transformResponse: [ƒ]transitional: {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}url: "https://fullstack.exercise.applifting.cz/articles"validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"[[Prototype]]: Objectmessage: "Request failed with status code 403"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}onabort: ƒ handleAbort()onerror: ƒ handleError()onload: nullonloadend: ƒ onloadend()onloadstart: nullonprogress: nullonreadystatechange: nullontimeout: ƒ handleTimeout()readyState: 4response: "{\"code\":\"UNAUTHORIZED\",\"message\":\"Access token is missing, invalid or expired\"}"responseText: "{\"code\":\"UNAUTHORIZED\",\"message\":\"Access token is missing, invalid or expired\"}"responseType: ""responseURL: "https://fullstack.exercise.applifting.cz/articles"responseXML: nullstatus: 403statusText: ""timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}withCredentials: false[[Prototype]]: XMLHttpRequestresponse: {data: {…}, status: 403, statusText: '', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}data: {code: 'UNAUTHORIZED', message: 'Access token is missing, invalid or expired'}headers: AxiosHeaders {content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}status: 403statusText: ""[[Prototype]]: Objectstack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43883:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42594:66)"[[Prototype]]: Error
App.js:55 acquired access_token from server: 6d713a98-f478-44cd-8474-09972cca3f48
App.js:55 acquired access_token from server: f5115513-7ff1-4294-be16-af25f060c14e
xhr.js:247          POST https://fullstack.exercise.applifting.cz/articles 403
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:142
wrap @ bind.js:5
App @ App.js:117
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
App.js:122 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Could you please advise me how to do it so that it waits for the response to come back from the server, because I have it in a logical order in the code, but there is apparently a delay in the request. Is await and async used for this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What api is this? It is possible that you don't need access token for get requests, but do need them for posts requests and that's why you are not getting an error for the get case.
Check your access token in 3 places:

1. When you get it from the server, in the .then().
2. Check to see it in the local storage after you set it in there. You can see it either by going to dev tools -> application -> local storage or programmatically by localStorage.getItem()
3. When you are sending the post requests, check the headers to make sure the token is ok (maybe it's coming as object object for example).